# How to create ActiveX control with menu bar?

Tags: c++, atl

Is there anybody knows how to create activeX control with menu bar and toolbars? or Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls are typically client area controls, windowed or windowless. Menus and toolbars, on the opposite, are owned and managed by the hosting application which is ActiveX control container. So the control's scope is client area only.

Provided that both container and control implement methods around [`IOleInPlaceFrame::InsertMenus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683987%28v=vs.85%29) it might be possible for the control to share menu with the application and provide its own entries onto it. I am not aware of such standard convention to manage shared toolbar.

Read more on shared menu in [Help Menu Merging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdteyst2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that. But it's not always an appreciated method because the hosting window has to provide unique experience for user with single menu.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/controls/article.php/c5531/Menu-in-ActiveX-Controls.htm